# Can't import in flashDevelop?

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash

Here is the problem:

http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/593315Sanstitre.png

in my source file, I imported as3isolib to make my own game. But unfortunately, FlashDevelop is not able to find the import that i am doing in my main class!

Thank you for helping me, I'm new with AS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed** I made a huge mistake, you only need to add the file in "src" from as3isolib.